# use Pandas library on Azure functions

Tags: pandas, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-function-app

I deployed an app to Azure function that uses pandas and it gives me error code 500.

It appears that the pandas library is not supported. It used to work with older version of of Azure function and I was able to edit the code in the portal but it's not supported not.

How can I use the pandas library now?

function app RUNTIME_VERSION = ~2.
I tried to change the RUNTIME_VERSION TO ~1 but the app does not function with ~1 so I have to use ~2.

Comment: May I know the service plan of your function, consumption plan or app service plan ?

Comment: Nothing I’m aware should prevent this. Be sure to add it to your requirements.txt file. Also using the remote dependency build may help - “func azure functionapp publish <name> —build remote”. Would help if you published exception text as well that app is throwing

Answer (score -1):

You just need to open the kudu console on Azure portal and run the command below:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Then it will install pandas.

[image]

The premise is your function plan is app service plan because kudu is not available in consumption plan in python function